# SharePoint: How to filter documents in a document library

Tags: sharepoint

I'd like to "hide" certain documents from certain users in all places where lists are displayed.  That is, the list of documents will be different for different users.  For example, for user1 I want to hide documents containing "abc" and for user2 I want to hide documents containing "def".

Is there a SharePoint web part (or something) that I can deploy which will execute some code that can filter the list for all of the sites?  Ideally, this "solution" would take as input a list and a username, and would return a subset of the list.  And SharePoint would only display the filtered list.  Also, for performance reasons, the input should not be the entire set of documents in the list, but rather just those that are displayed.

Also, I understand that one possible way to accomplish this is via permissions on the documents.  Unfortunately, permissions is not something I can take advantage of as the documents have to be, in essence, public.

Also, to be clear, I am not asking about what the code should like like that does the filtering (although examples might be helpful), but rather if there exists a mechanism to accomplish the type of filtering I need.

Thanks for your help,
Eric

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best solution is absolutely permissions but if you cant use it, you can use audience targeting. go to your document library settings and enable audience targeting. after enabling, you will have audience target field in your documents.

you can have more info about audience targetting here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261958.aspx

if this is not what you are looking for, you can create custom views on your library and create filters by using [Me] parameter for current user. e.g. you can create a multiple user field and write the names of people you dont want to see that document. after that you can create a view with a filter [Me] is not on that field. But you can not deny users access to document if he has permission on the document and knows the url of document.